# そこへゆくと、まだ固い莟を見つけ出して

Tags: meaning

知名度の高い執筆者ばかり適当に揃えて一冊の雑誌を作る編集は、例えて言えば、インスタント食品をうまく使って食卓を賑わす料理人みたいなものだ。失敗の危険は少ないかもしれないが、創る喜びは少ない。

そこへゆくと、まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる編集の仕事はそれ自体がひとつの芸術である。そういうことの可能なエディターはそれほど多くいるとは考えられないが、優れた才能の開花のかげにはきわめてしばしばこういう創造的編集が存在するのではあるまいか.

Ok I am going to try again at trying to solve this, don't blast me if I get something wrong.

> 1 - そこへゆくと

> If you go there? (Talking about perhaps the previous paragraph which I have included.) Or, does it mean to physically go there?

> 2 - まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる編集の仕事はそれ自体がひとつの芸術である ->

> An Editors job , like raising a flower, a hard bud that you find, and send to the warm summer wind..is naturally one kind of art form.

> 3 - そういうことの可能なエディターはそれほど多くいるとは考えられないが、優れた才能の開花のかげにはきわめてしばしばこういう創造的編集が存在するのではあるまいか.

> There are not a lot of editor's that can create this type of natural art like a gardener  BUT behind the flowering (shadows) of this great talent very often, is a creative editor.

Did I at least get the jist of it right?  I still do not know what そこへゆくと is...

Finally, I had to answer the following questions: which one is correct?

```
a - まだ有名でない執筆者の才能が花開くかげには、優秀な編集者がいる。
b - 雑誌をつくるということは、花を育てるように創造的で芸術的な仕事である。
c - 簡単につくられた雑誌より、時間をかげで編集された雑誌のほうが内容が良い。
d - 優秀な才能を持つ編集者がいれば、より良い雑誌がつくれるようになる。
```

I chose 'd' to be correct BUT I WAS WRONG, 'a' is the correct answer, why is 'a' correct?

Comment: Can you narrow this down to a specific question? Proofreading or translation check questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: 「そこへゆくと」で、辞書に載ってますね。　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E5%87%A6%E3%81%B8%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8/ 「そういう点からいうと。その点に関しては。」って書いてあります。

Comment: Weblio和英辞書には、https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%93%E3%81%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A8 「そこへいくと」 "in that respect、whereas、in contrast" って載ってます。

Comment: @Leebo  ah sorry about that, I will then close it if that's the case, I wanted someone to check my meaning of the passage....

Comment: @Leebo  I added the question to be added to the end, it is a multiple choice selection of 4 questions, I chose d, but it was wrong, a is correct.  Why is a correct and d wrong?

Comment: I think you need to slow down and think about what you're doing and what you're saying.  Even in the English you're saying things that are a bit odd.  For example, you say you chose "*number 4*" but there is no *number 4*, there are choices *a, b, c,* and *d*.  You also write, "*I had to answer the following questions*".  But what follows are statements (supposedly in response to a question) but it doesn't seem that you've provided the question for which you're meant to choose the *best* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less an answer than a *guide* to how you might try to read and understand sentences like these.  It seems you're getting stuck a lot and having difficulty figuring out how to parse the sentences.

So, let's take

> そこへゆくと、まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる編集の仕事はそれ自体がひとつの芸術である

---

The **first** thing I would do is just make sure I know how to read the kanji and what all the vocabulary means.

- [莟]{つぼみ} a bud, a young plant
- [春]{はる} spring (**not** *summer*)
- [編集]{へんしゅう} ...

---

**Next**, I would try to figure out what the basic structure of the sentence is.

Since the sentence ends in である you should expect the following structure

> Aは/がBである

So, we can boil the whole sentence down to

> 仕事はそれ自体が芸術である

Hmmm.  So, you'll need to figure out what's going on here with a marked topic and subject for the sentence.

But essentially this reduced sentence says

> As for the job, it is itself an art.

So now, you'd have the basic sentence.

---

**Now** we need to build up from this.

Here there are three things to consider

1. そこへゆくと
2. まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる
3. How does #1 relate to #2 (For example, is it part of the relative clause or the main sentence?)

I'm going to initially pretend like そこへゆくと isn't even there and just see if I can make sense of the bulk of the *relative* clause.

> まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる

This relative clause is broken into three parts marked by the verbs: 出して, 送り, and 育てる.  So, at a minimum, this relative clause is describing three aspects of 編集の仕事.  Given the form of 出して and 送り, I'll initially try to connect these using "*and*" in English.

*Now* take each of these one by one

> まだ固い莟を見つけ出して
> *Someone* discovers a still firm bud.

> これにあたたかい春の風を送り
> *Someone* sends it a warm Spring breeze

> 花に育てる
> *Someone* nurses [it] into a flower.

Putting these three parts together

> *Someone* finds the still firm bud, sends it a warm Spring breeze, and nurses it into a flower.

---

**Now** we need to connect the relative clause to what's happening in the main clause.  As noted  the relative clause modifies 編集の仕事.

> The job of being an editor, who finds a young, firm bud, sends it a warm Spring breeze, and nurses it into a flower....

And now we can complete the sentence.

> The job of being an editor is itself a kind of art, where the editor is someone who finds a young, firm bud, sends it a warm Spring breeze, and nurses it into a flower.

---

There's still the matter of そこへゆくと.  You could follow the lead suggested in the comments regarding this, but also you could just translate it literally into English

> If you're going to go there,....

This is referring to the build up of the previous paragraphs and amounts to saying

> If that's how you're going to think about things,

with the implication being *we can imagine the situation as follows* (though this is not explicitly spelled out).

---

OK. So what are the take-aways here?

1. As I've recommended before, *slow down*.
2. Take the time to write out the vocabulary by hand.
3. Actually break the sentence down into its parts.  Write these out on a sheet of paper so you can see it all in front of you.  This might seem tedious, but it's a good way to help train your brain into how to parse a Japanese sentence.
4. Make sure you've accounted for everything and you're not trying to force the sentence to say what you think it should say. (I think this is such an easy trap to fall into when starting with a new language:  we anticipate too quickly where we think we're being taken and then get confused because we're not really *hearing* what's being *said*.)

---

As I mentioned in the comments, you haven't really told us what question was being asked.  Without knowing that, it's hard to say why one choice is better than another.  But let's look at the choice you made and the choice that was marked as correct.

Your choice:

> 優秀な才能を持つ編集者がいれば、より良い雑誌がつくれるようになる。

Follow the same *principles* as I outlined above.  (1) Make sure you know what all the vocabulary means and how to read the kanji.  (2) break the sentence down into its most basic structures.  (3) Stitch everything back together.

I'll assume that you already did #1.  So for #2, the basic sentence is

> 雑誌がつくれるようになる
> You'll be able to create a magazine.

Go through all the steps I recommended for this sentence.  In the end, you should wind up with something like

> If there is an editor who has superior talent, then it will be possible to create a good magazine.

The choice marked as correct.

> まだ有名でない執筆者の才能が花開くかげには、優秀な編集者がいる。

you should be able to analyze this to be saying

> Behind the blossoming of the talent of a not-yet famous author there is a superior editor.

Given that the paragraphs you provided us in your question are focused more on authors than the publishing of a magazine, it seems clear that choice d is most likely not hitting the target (so to speak).

Comment: Considering what the previous paragraph says, it seems natural to think that まだ固い莟を見つけ出して、これにあたたかい春の風を送り、花に育てる modifies 編集 in a restrictive manner in reference to a contrasting type of editors, not 編集の仕事 in a non-restrictive manner, with そこへゆくと emphasizing the contrast between the two.

Comment: @aguijonazo I'm not sure I follow you on the matter of *restrictive* vs *non-restrictive* here.

Comment: @aguijonazo Also, I'm not sure it makes sense to say the clause is modifying 編集 unless 編集 actually can refer to the *editor* themself.  But, my dictionaries don't seem to allow the reading.  They all seem indicate to 編集者 to be used to refer to the editor.  It seems to me that it's less the *editing* that allows for the blossoming of *talent* but rather it's the performance of the job.  But, maybe I'm just missing your point.

Comment: This 編集 means 編集者. It is likened to 料理人 in the previous paragraph. The relative clause in the previous paragraph *restricts* the scope of 編集(者) to reference a particular (not-so-good) type of editors. Then, it is also natural to understand the relative clause in this paragraph to restrictively reference another (good) type of editors. The relative clause in your English translation is clearly non-restrictive in that it adds a general description to the job of an editor. I think "*the job of an editor who finds …*" would be more accurate.

Comment: @aguijonazo Thanks for the explanation about 編集.  But I'm still not following you on why you think my English is not restrictive.  I mean I know there's a lot of noise out there about *that* vs *which*, but **that** distinction is non-existent in my brand of English.  It's really an academese sort of distinction.  But I will amend my answer to match your recommendation.

Comment: Because your translation seems to say the job of being an editor is an art regardless of what kind of editor they are.

Comment: @aguijonazo After your previous comment, I understood better what you meant.  I completely agree with the distinction you're drawing.  All I'm saying is that whether I use *which* or *who/that* does not make any distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive in my brand of English.  But, if others feel otherwise, I'm happy to amend my question to better match the desired reading.  In other words, I don't dispute the *restrictive* nature of the clause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131464/discussion-between-a-ellett-and-aguijonazo).